# Data Binding: Pass LiveData as is to BindingAdapter and observe it using a LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I want to pass a `LiveData` as is to `BindingAdapter`.

Inside the `BindingAdapter` I want to do a `Transformations.map` and display different options the user can select and when clicked send the result back using the same `LiveData`.

In order to observe the `LiveData` in the `BindingAdapter` I need access to the `LifecycleOwner`, ideally of the fragment view. I need that if I want to call `.observe` on the liveData or set the `LifecycleOwner` on the new binding I create inside the `BindingAdapter`.

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, I'd like to recommend you not to go down the road of placing too much of your business logic into your `BindingAdapter`s. Besides it being a good practice to use binders to simply set style attributes, I have personally seen *spaghetti-code disasters* made by placing too much logic into the adapters. This is a really sketchy practice as the code is run for every element that listens to your binding, every time your livedata changes so your logic can get pretty hectic, very quickly and your app performance can be decreased quite swiftly, too.

Having said that, I don't think you should be passing in `LiveData` into your binding but instead the `Object E` that is being held in your livedata. This way you can:

1. keep your work inside the fragment that both has a `LifecycleOwner` and is the recommended way to observe for changes
2. pass into your `LiveData` instance the result of your `Transformation` and
3. display it in your UI by receiving it directly through your binding

This way your adapter has only the logic to display the result/results and all the work is being handled correctly by the fragment.

---

**ViewModel Implementation**

If you'd like to take this a step further, following Google's recommended Architecture Components, I'd suggest you to place the logic inside your ViewModel (should you be following the MVVM pattern) and avoid the use of the fragment altogether. You'd place the `LiveData` variable inside your viewModel (say `var itemColor: LiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>(R.color.colorPrimary)`) , connect it to your binding through xml
i.e.

```
app:showColor="@{viewModel.itemColor}"
```

and place all the logic of your Transformations inside a function in the viewModel. Setting the value to `itemColor` would directly send the value to your bindingadapter (`showColor`) and you could use the value as needed without even touching the fragment or observing the variable!

*Note*: please remember to set the lifecycleOwner to your binding inside the fragment as so : `binding.lifecycleOwner = this`, otherwise the adapter will not listen for changes.

I hope this helped, Panos.

Comment: you are right, but let's assume the project is written in a certain way and I can't change it just before the deadline

Comment: You could probably use data-binding to pass in an instance of the lifecycleOwner. I'm not too sure on the implications of this, there may be some leaks going on there. I still recommend you try a different approach, preferably one that doesn't involve observing in the adapters. *Sidenote: I think, adapters are already observers in a sense, try `binding.executePendingBindings()` after any new change.*